# Can I use file streaming approach in android?

Tags: java, android, file, streaming, nio

I am saving XML data as a string in my app's SharedProperties.
Can I apply Java streaming techniques if I save it in some file instead? Is there a standard place to save files for streaming in android apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Context`'s [openFileOutput (String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)) and [openFileInput (String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)) methods to read and write files.